# Syntax error in MySQL function using WHILE

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a function for MySQL that will strip all non-digit characters from a submitted phone number.  I keep getting a syntax error.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION cleanPhone(phone VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
  DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
  DECLARE clean VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE idx TINYINT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE ch CHAR(1);
  DECLARE digits CHAR(10) DEFAULT '0123456789';

  WHILE idx <= LENGTH(phone) DO
    SET ch = MID(phone,idx,1);
    IF LOCATE(ch, digits) > 0 THEN SET clean = CONCAT(clean, ch);
    SET idx = idx + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN clean;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to execute this code, I get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '
>
> ```
> WHILE;
>   RETURN clean;
> END
> ```
>
> ' at line 13

Answer (score 1):

You missed `END IF;`

```
  WHILE idx <= LENGTH(phone) DO
    SET ch = MID(phone,idx,1);
    IF LOCATE(ch, digits) > 0 THEN SET clean = CONCAT(clean, ch);
    END IF;
    SET idx = idx + 1;
  END WHILE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close if block.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION cleanPhone(phone VARCHAR(20)) RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
  DETERMINISTIC 
BEGIN
  DECLARE clean VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT '';
  DECLARE idx TINYINT DEFAULT 1;
  DECLARE ch CHAR(1);
  DECLARE digits CHAR(10) DEFAULT '0123456789';

  WHILE idx <= LENGTH(phone) DO
    SET ch = MID(phone,idx,1);
    IF LOCATE(ch, digits) > 0 THEN SET clean = CONCAT(clean, ch);
      SET idx = idx + 1;
    END IF;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN clean;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```